# problems when mounting a USB storage on linux

Tags: c, linux, usb

I'm working on a C program that needs to mount a USB storage and write to it. It can be mounted, but a following "mount" command doesn't show it. I'm really confused.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mount.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        char *usb_path = argv[1];
        int ret = mount(usb_path, "/mnt/usb_mount_point", "ext3", 0, NULL);
        if (ret == 0) {
                printf("mount() succeeded.\n");
        } else {
                printf("mount() failed: %d, %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        }
        return (ret);
}
```

What I did is:
I found an USB storage of vfat type, and format it to ext3 using "`mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdb4`"; it's strange that "fdisk -l" still shows it as vfat:

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb4   *           1        1890    15180768+   c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

I then use my program to mount it: "`./my_prog /dev/sdb4`". It succeeded, and I can cd into /mnt/usb_mount_point to work on the USB storage.

But a "mount" command cannot see it. Anything wrong here?

Comment: Please add some code: _"Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it"_ as asked of you in the help section

Comment: Code and more details added... thanks.

Comment: mkfs does not change the partition type, so it will show as FAT until you change the type with fdisk or similar.

Comment: Hmm... so what is the right way to 'format' a USB storage? Or, is 'format' the right term?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mount command will defer to the content of the `/etc/mtab` file when looking for mounted file systems.

On some systems this is an actual, honest-to-goodness normal file, which means that **something** has to update it. The program that updates it is generally the `mount` command itself. The contents of this file **are not** a guarantee that the file system has been mounted or not; for instance there is an option to mount - `-n`, which says to not update the `/etc/mtab` file.

On quite a few linux environments, it's a symbolic link to the `/proc/mounts` file which contains the kernel's understanding of what's been mounted, and this is the true list of what's been mounted.

By using the `mount` system call, you bypass the mechanism that updates the `/etc/mtab` file, so if it's not a symbolic link, then you end up with it acting similarly to using `mount -n`.

Check the `/proc/mounts` file and you will see that the file system is mounted.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'll try it tomorrow - I don't have the machine at hand. One related question: if the USB is physically unpluged from the machine without calling umount before, what's the correct behavior to clean up? What i see now is that, after the USB is unpluged, 'ls /mnt/usb_mount_point/...' gets I/O error, and using 'umount /mnt/usb_mount_point' will clean it. So I guess the correct behavior is to call umount() after it's unplugged, but how can I get notified in the program after the USB is unplugged? Thanks.

Comment: Calling umount after removing the drive cleans up the mount point but caching behaviour of the OS could leave you with garbage on the disk if it was not flushed out before the drive was removed. Ideally you should call umount **before** the drive is removed. If you want to monitor USB add/remove events you should plug into [libudev](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/libudev/). See some [tutorial documentation](http://www.signal11.us/oss/udev/) for using the monitoring interface